# Need to remove some items from a IList Selenium C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

When I execute below command I'm getting more than 3000 items to my elm variable. Then I have to pass them in to a string array.

The below list contain so many blank data and there are some items which contains characters.
But I need only elements with numbers.
So is there any problematical way to remove all the blank elements and the elements with characters.

```cs
     IList<IWebElement> elm = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("spy14"));
```

I was trying with a for each loop, but I stucked on some place.

EDIT:

```cs
    elm = elm.Where(x => !x.Text.Contains(" ")).ToArray();
```

With @PDHide's help I was able to get this thing done with above code.

Comment: Voting for closing because this question is regarding programming. On Stack Overflow people can tell you about list filters.

Comment: I was thinking IList<IWebElement> are mostly used by test engineers ,and that's why I post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get blank data as its a IWebElement type list. If you meant that when you try to get text it returns empty for few elements then use:

```
 elm = elm.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text)).ToList();
```

You will get elements for which Text is not Null or empty:

**Reference**: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__

For getting only numbers try

```
 elm = elm.Where(x => decimal.TryParse(x.Text, out decimal myInt)).ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah its the text.

Comment: This works fine to remove empty values.Thanks and I will mark this as a solution,But what about removing entries with string values?

Comment: @ChathuD add filter for getting only numbers

Comment: That didnt work.Any way thanks for the support.Aftet the above code i was trying elm = elm.Where(x => !x.Text.Contains("s")).ToArray(); and this seems to be working.

Comment: @ChathuD there was a extra semi colon you can try the new code